# Deriving formulae from clinical research publications

Tags: sample-size, clinical-trials

I am planning a research project with hypertension patients and am now trying to find the appropriate sample size for my clinical research proposal. I have found an [interesting research project](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamainternalmedicine/fullarticle/2678454?utm_campaign=articlePDF&utm_medium=articlePDFlink&utm_source=articlePDF&utm_content=jamainternmed.2018.0447) that had a comparable focus. They have listed their sample size, the corresponding power and their alpha, as well as their accepted SD. I had wanted to understand their research approach, but I was unable to find the corresponding formulae. If anyone could help me and has an inkling as to which formulae they used or where I could start to look, that would be incredibly helpful.

Thanks a lot[image]

Comment: There is a choice of free software to compute sample sizes for unpaired t-tests. `G*power` is often used, explanation here: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/gpower/power-analysis-for-two-group-independent-sample-t-test/ .  The `R` package `pwr` may be the better choice if you prefer text based computing https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pwr/index.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! That really helps! One thing I am still not quite getting: from your experience, is the SD here derived from previous literature or does it come from the statistical anticipation, i.e. the available sample size?

Comment: Without regard to any specific work or authors I would generally not totally exclude the option of reverse sample size estimation: In clinical work you often have strong assumptions about the feasible numbers but little grounds to determine the minimal effect size. If your ethics committee or preregistration platform expect ex ante power analysis it is computationally simple to adapt the effect size to the numbers instead of the other way around. It is not what you are officially supposed to do but I know of real life situations in which the temptation is high.